# Deciding between mongoDb vs Mysql vs hadoop

Tags: mysql, mongodb, bigdata, nosql

I am in the process of designing and implementing the data layer of an application. Did some basic research and found that NoSql possibly looks good for me due to less complex structures and simplicity.

My req would be to host a single table with close to 800,000 records which is not much in my opinion and even the poorest DB could handle this easily.

However my reads will be relatively high. Close to 200,000 at any instant of time. My read query :

**Reads :(200,000 at any instant)**

```
    Select Sum(columnA, columnB),  Sum(columnC, columnD) from Table where 
( column E ='X' OR column F='Y'  or column G='X' OR column H='Y' ) Group 
by columnK Having Count(*) =4 order by columnK
```

**Writes: 30 row Inserts per minute (No Updates)**

Given this, i find any normal database would do . But in my case every millisecond counts as this is a financial application and any reduction in response times would be helpful. What is the best approach?

Comment: If you don't need to scale out, isn't a run of the mill RDBMS enough for you?

Comment: Thanks Havnar. I will need to scale out soon. Speed and response time is exactlyy what i am after to put it precisely. If one option saves me even 5 milliseconds than the other i would go with that.

Comment: The numbers look a bit odd to me,  the description too (financial data has less demand for speed and a high demand for durability and hence is more often message driven than not), but be it. 800k records of non-interconnected data?  MMapped 2-dimensional data structure. Which is what MongoDB does. Keep in mind that only document writes are atomic, which isn't a problem with proper data modeling, though.

Comment: Hadoop is generally better for longer running queries(hours and days), whereas MongoDB is generally better for quick queries (less than a minute).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go the NoSQL route if you think that's going to be needed in your case, I would suggest looking at Hbase, MongoDB and Cassandra as potential competitors.

Also know that they don't support SQL out of the box. (for HBase you could use Phoenix as a SQL layer on top of HBase for instance)

NoSQL doesn't work in the same way as normal (My)SQL works, so you might want to read up on the inner workings first before you make a choice.

Do a thorough comparison in a POC and see what works best for your usecase.